# Linear time algorithm to make a graph strongly connected

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

We have a weakly acyclic digraph.

Also we are given a set A which holds vertices of G that have in-degree zero and a set B which holds vertices that have out-degree zero. (size of A is smaller then size of B).

On top of that, we also know that if items in A and B have a particular order (e.g. A = a1, a2, ..., am and B = b1, b2, ... , bn) a DFS started at ai visits bi (1≤ i ≤ m).

Is it possible to design a linear time algorithm which makes G strongly connected by adding to it as few edges as possible?

Comment: "DFS started at ai visits bi (1≤ i ≤ m)" Don't get it. Is there (1) repeating elements in A and empty in B OR (2) your graph has a special property, that starting from vertex in-degree zero we can achieve a strictly one vertex of out-degree zero (3) none of that (give your explanation in that case) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add arcs b<sub>j</sub> -> a<sub>j+1</sub> for j = 1, ..., m-1 and arcs b<sub>j</sub> -> a<sub>1</sub> for j = m, ..., n.

The resulting graph is strongly connected because the a's and b's are strongly connected by the added arcs and the paths from a<sub>i</sub> to b<sub>i</sub> and, for every node x, there exist i, j such that there exists a path in the original graph from a<sub>i</sub> to x and a path in the original graph from x to b<sub>j</sub>.

We cannot use fewer arcs, because an outgoing arc must be added to each of b<sub>1</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>.

Comment: It's very simple. But there is question. There is ambiguity in original statement **I asked about**. If you have directed acyclic graph where the undirected version of it is a connected graph AND number of vertex with in-degree zero (A) less than or equal to number of vertex with out-degree zero (B) it doesn't mean that you have matching between A and B. **If you can prove it - DO IT. With out this fact it's not an answer**.

Comment: @Wisdom's Wind Why should I have to prove what's clearly a hypothesis in the current question wording?

Comment: There may be a problem with this solution. Consider a graph composed of two rings, X and Y, and an isolated point. There is a link from X to Y and from Y to the isolated point. The isolated point is the only member of set B. It is connected as an acyclic graph, but not strongly connected, because you cannot get from Y to X, or from the isolated node to Y. Because A has no elements, your proposal would not add any links.

Comment: I've asked (does) "your graph has a special property" (that DFS started at ai visits bi (1≤ i ≤ m))? Author asked: "A and B were set of vertices, they gave no extra information". It's because graph with specified properties may not have A to B match (where A and B is a **sets**). 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/dajbD.png

Comment: @mcdowella A and B are nonempty because G is assumed acyclic.

Comment: @Wisdom's Wind Less yelling, more "what can you do if the order is not an input?"

Answer (score 1):

Edited - Following does not produce solution with least links:

You can run http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm in linear time. I propose that you do this and note that "no strongly connected component will be identified before any of its successors". Therefore the first strongly component out of the graph must not be a successor of any of the other components. I suggest that every time you emit a strongly connected component which has no successor, then you add a link connecting it to this first component. I suggest that you also add a link every time you essentially restart the Tarjan algorithm with a non-recursive call to strongconnect(), connecting the first component to the vertex you are restarting at.

With these links you can get from the first strong component to every other component, and from every other component to the first strong component. - unfortunately this is not necessarily the solution with the least links - see second comment by Per below.

Comment: How do you handle more than one component with no predecessors?

Comment: My intention is that secondary components with no predecessors are the components at which the Tarjan algorithm restarts with non-recursive calls, so they get links from the first component, and become reachable from it. Their successors, or themselves, get links to the first component, completing the cycle. However since the point I raised on your answer was wrong, perhaps I am wrong here too?

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, then on the graph {a1->b1, a1->b2, a2->b2}, strong component {a1} could be the first emitted, followed by {b1} and {b2}, so b1 and b2 get links back to a1. Connecting a1 and a2 requires one more link for a total of 3, versus the 2 required to connect b1->a2, b2->a1.